# Stud under siding at corner of house?

Tags: siding

I am trying to install a shade sail and would like to attach one point to the side of my house. If I were to put the attachment point into the vertical siding at the corner of the house, should there reliably be a stud running underneath that area? Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The vertical trim you're looking at is called a corner board. Depending on which wall was framed first when the house was being built you might have the edge or the face of the stud to drill into.

Drill a couple small holes, if the bit drops into the hole with no resistance then you're missing the stud. Make sure you fill those holes with a paintable caulking.

Whatever you do make sure you use a reasonably sized lag or eye bolt, the lateral and vertical forces from those sails can be quite intense depending on your location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But the best way to know for sure is by drilling a small hole (say 1/8" or less in diameter) with a long drill bit. If you feel it 'bite', you've got a stud.